# Change element name with xml.modify or other method in TSQL

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xml.modify

Suppose you have a TSQL query:

```
1 as 'Category1/@Level',
2 as 'Category2/@Level',
t.MainCat as 'Category1', 
t.SubCat as 'Category2'
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('Taxonomy')
```

which generates following result:

```
<Taxonomy>
      <Category1 Level="1">Clothing</Category1>
      <Category2 Level="2">Jeans</Category2>
</Taxonomy>
```

The element Category1 and Category2 have unique names for the sql query to generate and convert in to xml format. That's why I used Category1 and Category2. I would like the end result to be like this:

```
<Taxonomy>
      <Category Level="1">Clothing</Category>
      <Category Level="2">Jeans</Category>
</Taxonomy>
```

This could be done using XML EXPLICIT [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944539/using-attribute-more-than-once-in-for-xml-path-t-sql-query-with-same-element-nam/24951606#24951606), but since my code is much larger it becomes very cluttered and complex quite fast.

With xml.modify you can change values or attributes, but not the element itself.

Is there a way to store the first query result in a @X1 xml variable and then change the element Category1 & Category2 into Category and put it into variable @X2? Something like a search and replace used in text files, but then during the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you may use nesting:

```
select
    (select 1 as '@Level', 'Clothing'
        for xml path('Category'), type),
    (select 2 as '@Level', 'Jeans'
        for xml path('Category'), type)
for xml path('Taxonomy');
```

or `values` clause to construct list of categories before forming output xml:

```
select Cat.Level as '@Level', Cat.Value as 'text()'
from (values
        (1, 'Clothing')
        ,(2, 'Jeans')
    ) Cat(Level, Value)
for xml path('Category'), root('Taxonomy');
```

Comment: Tried both ways, and the subselect method worked very nice, also as a part of much larger query. It kind of pastes them together in one large xml. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

sneaking a null in between elements can do the trick:

```
Select
1 as 'Category/@Level',
t.MainCat as "Category",
null,
2 as 'Category/@Level',
t.SubCat as "Category"
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT('Taxonomy')
```

Comment: thanks, wow! All it took was an extra NULL?! And it doesn't harm the code in anyway apperently. That's a neat little trick.

Comment: However, in my larger code it takes out the structure of the xml. The NULL 'undoubles' the column/element name, but also unties the relation between them, so I have to go for i-one answer, sorry.

Comment: maybe the larger code need some tweak or reordering to work as well to apply this solution, but since it's now working with a different approach no need to fix what is not broken.